# unable to install anything in Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker

Docker newbie here, I want to create a new image based on another image I pulled from Dockerhub which by itself works great but I wanted to add some tools to it.
My Dockerfile is very small and it already fails:

```
FROM aunsbjerg/docker-kinetis-design-studio

RUN echo "hello world!"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
```

The hello world line by itself seems to work fine but as soon as I try to install any program, it fails with:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Why is this and how do I get past it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container’s setup isn’t finished, because `kinetis-design-studio` assumes it can talk to `udev` and that doesn’t work here.

To fix that, run

```
sed -i 's/udevadm/#udevadm/' /var/lib/dpkg/info/kinetis-design-studio.postinst && dpkg --configure --pending
```

as the first commands in your Dockerfile (`RUN ...`).